# iframe dissapears after loading completely firefox mobile

Tags: android, firefox, iframe

I have an iframe on my page, it works everywhere except on my android mobile device in firefox version 68.1. Even if I request the desktop site, the iframe disappears.

Here's the iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://itch.io/embed/283412?linkback=true&amp;border_width=0&amp;bg_color=0c0c0c&amp;fg_color=e0e0e0&amp;link_color=20b000&amp;border_color=3c3c3c" width="550" height="165" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Works on other mobile browsers including chrome and safari. Any ideas?